# Why does a renderable array work in an if statement, but not show anything if I dpm it?

Tags: 7, theming

I have information stored in a renderable array (I'm reasonably sure that's what it's called), and can use it in an if statement, eg:

```
if (!empty($element['singleProduct'])) {
  //do something
```

but if I try to use dpm above this, eg:

```
dpm($element['singleProduct']);
if (!empty($element['singleProduct'])) {
  //do something
```

dpm shows nothing.

Obviously I do have devel on. I can dpm other things. And I've tried clearing cache and registry.

Would anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: where do you call that specific dpm(). if you put something like dpm('test') directly before or after this dpm does it show?

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r` to dump the values and add a `die("called");` right after the code. This way you're absolutely sure something is printed.

Comment: @StefanKorn yes dpm('test'); works